# Relax at home after work

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

What phrase would you use to express that you relax at home after work and don't do any special activity ?

If what I want to say is that the only thing I do after work is resting, I think I could use one of these

> I take a break at home after work.
>   I get some rest at home after work.

However, I am not sure what expression I can use to mean that

> I don't do anything special at home after work but I just chill out at home
>
> chill out at home

feels the closest to what I mean to say but I am wondering if there is any other way of saying this, possibly a little bit more formal.

Comment: Perhaps: `When I get home from work, I just like to sit down and relax for a while.`  This doesn't feel too lazy or out of the ordinary.  Informal, I would say : `After work, I'm gonna chill for a bit.` That uses slang though so be careful :)

Comment: Another slang phrase is "kick back".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following phrases:

> - ...unwind at home.
> - ...take it easy at home.
> - ...loosen up (although not very commonly used) at home.
> - ...take a break.

There are many words for relaxing in English, although you have to be careful in formal language because many of them are in the "slang" region.